# Gitlab Runner - listen_address not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, gitlab, devops

I am setting up gitlab-runner locally on my mac to be able to run build and test scripts using docker. I have gone through the installation instructions listed on the Gitlab runners page to install the runner locally:

```
# Download the binary for your system
sudo curl --output /usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner https://gitlab-runner-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/binaries/gitlab-runner-darwin-amd64

# Give it permissions to execute
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner

# The rest of commands execute as the user who will run the Runner
# Register the Runner (steps below), then run
cd ~
gitlab-runner install
gitlab-runner start
```

From what I can tell it is installed fine. I then registered a runner like so:

```
sudo gitlab-runner register --url https://gitlab.com/ --registration-token $REGISTRATION_TOKEN
```

(I obviously replaced `$REGISTRATION_TOKEN` with my token). When it prompts me for additional details I have entered the following:

- Tags: (I left this blank)
- Enter an executor: `docker`
- Enter the default docker image: `node:14.0.0`

I then get the following message:

> Runner registered successfully. Feel free to start it, but if it's
> running already the config should be automatically reloaded!

When I then navigate to the root of my project I try and run gitlab-runner run but I get the following error:

```
Starting multi-runner from /Users/ben/.gitlab-runner/config.toml...  builds=0
WARNING: Running in user-mode.                     
WARNING: Use sudo for system-mode:                 
WARNING: $ sudo gitlab-runner...                   
                                                   
Configuration loaded                                builds=0
listen_address not defined, metrics & debug endpoints disabled  builds=0
[session_server].listen_address not defined, session endpoints disabled  builds=0
^CWARNING: [runWait] received stop signal             builds=0 stop-signal=interrupt
WARNING: Graceful shutdown not finished properly    builds=0 error=received stop signal: interrupt
WARNING: Starting forceful shutdown                 StopSignal=interrupt builds=0
All workers stopped. Can exit now                   builds=0
```

When I look at the config.toml if looks like it may be missing some configuration in there as the error above may suggest? Here is a cat of the entire file:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800
```

I'm not sure why i'm receiving this error message? Does my config look alright? When searching the issue I found another thread that said to just set "Can run untagged jobs" to yes which I have done but it still does not work...

Answer (score 3):

It makes sense that you're having problems with the configuration.

If you read carefully the output, it says that you're running in `user-mode`, so I suppose you started the runner by using `gitlab-runner`.

Problem is that you registered your runner using `sudo`, so you configured the `system-mode` under `/etc/gitlab-runner/`. This configuration is loaded when you start `gitlab-runner` with `sudo`.

In order to verify that, you will be able to see the registered configuration under `/etc/gitlab-runner/`, with all the additional sections regarding Docker Runners and so on, instead of the basic configuration that you have under `~/.gitlab-runner/` which I suppose is the one you attached to your question.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Sorry but I am so lost as how to fix this. What you mentioned above is verified but using sudo or not/ uninstalling and reinstalling still doesnt work

Comment: Okay, just try to register again the runner without `sudo` rights and tell me what problem do you face.